# How do I adjust the date time format for an output parameter in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an output parameter in oracle called outTime of type DATE. The format for this is set as yyyy-mm-dd and I need to be able to include the time from a table when I select into it.

I keep getting an error : date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

here is the insert into statement.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Table_Time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') into outTime
FROM Table_One;
```

the out parameter is declared as

```
outTime OUT DATE;
```

within a stored procedure in a package of other procedures.

I keep finding ways to set the format globally but I only need to set the format for this instance.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DATE` does not have a format.  A string representation of a date has a format but a `DATE` does not.

If `Table_Time` is a `VARCHAR2` (a string representation of a date) in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`, then you would want to use `TO_DATE` to convert the string into a `DATE` (I assume that there is a single row in `table_one` in this example, otherwise the `SELECT ... INTO` will raise a `no_data_found` or a `too_many_rows` exception.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(Table_Time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  into outTime
  FROM Table_One;
```

If `Table_Time` is a `DATE`, you would simply assign it to `outTime`

```
SELECT Table_Time
  into outTime
  FROM Table_One;
```

When you want to display `outTime`, you'll need to convert the `DATE` to a string representation of a date (a `VARCHAR2`).  At that point, you can use the `TO_CHAR` function.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast and clear response. I think I always considered date existing only as a string instead of recognizing it as it's own abstract object. What I did in this instance then was change it to_char from the date object into a varchar variable and then back to_date into the out parameter so the application could use it.

Comment: @dee - Why would you convert a `DATE` to a `VARCHAR2` only to convert it back to a `DATE`?  Why not simply assign the original `DATE` to `outTime`?  Adding two unnecessary conversion steps to your code is going to make it slower and more error-prone.

Comment: I agree it seems convoluted but I can not assign the date to outTime as it only shows the date as YYYY-MM-DD. The value for the Table_Time field has a format of YYYY-MM-DD HR24:MI:SS. I need to convert the date to char to get the correct format. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dee - You're missing something.  If `table_out.table_time` is a `DATE`, it does not have a format.  A `DATE` does not have a format.  It does always have a time component.  That time component is not always displayed when you convert a `DATE` to a string representation of a date which is what would have to have happened in order to convert a `DATE` to a sting with the format YYYY-MM-DD.  If both `outTime` and `Table_Time` are of type `DATE`, you should just do a direct assignment.  That will copy both the day and the time component.

Comment: That makes complete sense however when I first selected directly into the outTime date parameter I only had date appear as YYYY-MM-DD. After your suggestion and my admittedly convoluted solution it then displayed the full value of time from the Table_Time field. Now, after changing it back it to directly selecting Type DATE into DATE, I get the full value of date including hr, mm, and ss; as you say I should. Must be magic.... :/ or more likely something I did wrong the first time around. Thanks for the help.